# Spring 4: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter does not support application/javascript for jsonp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsonp, spring-4

Using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and Jackson libraries v2.5.4

Want to use JSONP in my REST Services using Spring 4; 
Spring 4 supports JSONP out of the box.

**CONFIGURATION**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven
    content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
...
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Using contentNegotiationManager in following manner

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />


    <!-- Configuration of Path Extension Based ContentNegotiationStrategy -->
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />

    <!-- Configuration of Request Parameter Based ContentNegotiationStrategy -->
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="parameterName" value="formatType" />
    <property name="mediaTypes" ref="mediaTypesMapping" />
    <!-- Configuration of HTTP ACCEPT Header Based ContentNegotiationStrategy -->
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

</bean>
```

Here is the MediaTypeMapping

```
<util:map id="mediaTypesMapping">
    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    <entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript" />
</util:map>
```

Here is the jsonpParameterNames

```
<util:set id="jsonpParameterNames">
    <value>param1</value>
    <value>param2</value>
    <value>param3</value>
</util:set>
```

Deployed my REST Service.

- hitting the following URL gives data in json format

  ```
   /contextRoot/info/1?formatType=json
  ```
- hitting the following URL gives data in xmlformat

  ```
   /contextRoot/info/1?formatType=xml
  ```
- hitting the following URL gives 406 EXCEPTION

  ```
   /contextRoot/info/1?formatType=jsonp&param1=callback1
  ```

**Observations**

On doing investigation, discovered that MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
does not supports application/javascript.

Surprised by this since Spring 4 claims to support JSONP Out of the box.

Furthermore, MappingJackson2JsonView does support JSONP out of the box.

**Question**

Am I missing something in the configuration which once added will enable me to use content type application/javascript out of the box with SPRING 4 for JSONP?

***EDIT***

Here is my ControllerAdvice Configuration:

```
<bean id="jsonpAdvice"
    class="com.advice.AccountServiceControllerJsonpAdvice">
    <constructor-arg ref="jsonpParameterNames" />
</bean>
```

And here is the ControllerAdvice

```
 public class AccountServiceControllerJsonpAdvice extends
    AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {

private String[] callbackList = {"callback"};

public String[] getCallbackList() {
    return callbackList;
}

public void setCallbackList(String[] callbackList) {
    this.callbackList = callbackList;
}

public AccountServiceControllerJsonpAdvice(String... callbackList) {
    super(callbackList);
}
}
```

However, this does not enable my application to understand a URL like following and returns a 406 error

```
   /contextRoot/info/1?formatType=jsonp&param1=callback1
```

It only makes my application understand a request URL like following and return a JSONP response:

```
   /contextRoot/info/1?param1=callback1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring 4.1+ supports JSONP, but it's not a conversion format per se.

`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` supports `"application/json"` and `"*+json"` media types, but does not support `"application/javascript"`. If it did, then you'd expect it to **parse javascript code, which is not the case**.

Here, we're merely wrapping the output to make it `"application/javascript"`, but really, it's still JSON.

Your current configuration is disabling content negotiation with HTTP Accept headers (why?). In order to support JSONP you only need this in your MVC configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

And an additional `ControllerAdvice` like this ([see reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-jsonp)):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {

    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }
}
```

That's it.

Now you'll get:

```
GET /contextRoot/info/1
// will return what's best depending on the Accept header sent by the client

GET /contextRoot/info/1.xml
// will return XML

GET /contextRoot/info/1.json
// will return JSON

GET /contextRoot/info/1.json?callback=myFunction
// will return JSONP wrapped in a "myFunction" call
```

In your case, you should:

1. Remove `"application/javascript"` from your media types mappings, or for backwards compatibility associate `"jsonp"` with the `"application/json"` media type.
2. Use `GET /contextRoot/info/1?formatType=json&param1=callback1`

See [AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice.html) for more details on the implementation.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am using controllerAdvice as well. However, it only supports JSONP when URL is like:  /contextRoot/info/1?param1=callback1                 Instead, I want the URL to be of the format:  /contextRoot/info/1?formatType=jsonp&param1=callback1;

Comment: Don't we implicitly intend to work with application/javascript media Type when we intend to work with JSONP format?     Even MappingJackson2JsonView works with application/javascript. So why is that enabled to handle Javascript code?

Comment: A converter should be able to read/write content - Jackson can't parse javascript source code... The MappingJackson2JsonView is a one-way process as well: writing, not reading.

Comment: JSONP only supports GET request, Not PUT. So no data can be sent (that too in JSONP format) with a GET request. So how does one needs to parse application/javascript or JSONP data? Is it possible to have a scenario where Request itself is in JSONP format ?

Comment: Let me also explain the criticality of this to me: We are migrating to Spring 4 and before we had custom implementation for JSONP support. And we used URLs of the format ---- "contextRoot/info/12?format=jsonp&callback=value". ----We need to maintain backward compatibility of the REST URL as we migrate to Spring 4.

Comment: Exactly - that's why it doesn't make sense to have "application/javascript" as a conversion format - this is merely a wrapped format within our JSON arrangements. I've edited my answer - you should be able to associate "jsonp" with the JSON format in order to map it to the jackson converter. The JSONP request parameter should do the rest!

Comment: Well, yes it works. Thank You Very very much for your support. I now feel why did not I try that before. The idea that application/javascript is media type for JSONP, kind of obsessed me. So effectively Spring seems to be taking a step towards associating JSONP with media type application/json. Next I need to assess what is the impact of this observation on the whole and on my custom exception View Resolver since there also I map application/javascript type (For JSONP) with MappingJackson2ViewResolver.

Comment: MappingJackson2JsonView must return application/javascript media type for jsonp requests to overcome CORS. Therefore, it supports application/javascript.