# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map] and content type [application/javascript]

Tags: spring, web-services, jsonp

I'm consuming a web service that return un JSONP object like this:

```
jQueryxxx_xx({
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN JUAN, LUCANAS, AYACUCHO",
      "ubigeo": "050616",
      "x": "-74.1991371264406",
      "y": "-14.6514315472295"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN JUAN, SIHUAS, ANCASH",
      "ubigeo": "021909",
      "x": "-77.5820769245717",
      "y": "-8.64612162557643"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN JUAN, CASTROVIRREYNA, HUANCAVELICA",
      "ubigeo": "090410",
      "x": "-75.6349774079376",
      "y": "-13.2032560496248"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN JUAN, CAJAMARCA, CAJAMARCA",
      "ubigeo": "060112",
      "x": "-78.5005693425229",
      "y": "-7.2909846278869"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN LUIS, LIMA, LIMA",
      "ubigeo": "150134",
      "x": "-76.9972475943101",
      "y": "-12.0740682897166"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN JOSE, LAMBAYEQUE, LAMBAYEQUE",
      "ubigeo": "140311",
      "x": "-79.9661756947746",
      "y": "-6.76677043459326"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN LUIS, SAN PABLO, CAJAMARCA",
      "ubigeo": "061203",
      "x": "-78.8683707221198",
      "y": "-7.15717727393363"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN LUIS, CARLOS FERMIN FITZCARRALD, ANCASH",
      "ubigeo": "020701",
      "x": "-77.3291574143902",
      "y": "-9.09439276715693"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN LUIS, CAÑETE, LIMA",
      "ubigeo": "150514",
      "x": "-76.4282649580734",
      "y": "-13.0502707531236"
    },
    {
      "ubicacion": "SAN JOSE, PACASMAYO, LA LIBERTAD",
      "ubigeo": "130705",
      "x": "-79.4564509393214",
      "y": "-7.34696446146118"
    }
  ],
  "elapsed": 0.036
},"elapsed":0.036})
```

I'm using RestTemplate object of Spring 3.1

This is my configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as 
        beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="xxxx" />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:servicios.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:other.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views 
        directory -->

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="reHttpConnectionManager"
        class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">
        <property name="params">
            <bean
                class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams">
                <property name="soTimeout" value="60000" />
                <property name="connectionTimeout" value="90000" />
                <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="500" />
                <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="500" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="reRequestFactory"
        class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="readTimeout" value="90000" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                <property name="httpConnectionManager" ref="reHttpConnectionManager" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="reRequestFactory" />
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                <!-- <entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript" /> -->
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <!-- JSON View -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />

                <!-- XML View -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                            <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>


            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <import resource="config.xml"/>

</beans>
```

In my code, I invoke fron this way:

```
Object respuesta = restTemplate.getForObject(urlSearch, Map.class, parametros);
//parametros is of type Map<String, Object>
```

I get following error:

```
09:45:22,668 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map] and content type [application/javascript]

09:45:22,668 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:84)

09:45:22,668 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:454)

09:45:22,668 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:417)

09:45:22,668 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:214)
```

I've tried to include application/javascript support:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converterJSONP = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            converterJSONP.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application/javascript")));
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converterJSONP);
```

I thought that will solve problem, but don't, I get this error:

```
Invalid token character '/' in token "application/javascript"
```

Well, How I can configure for my web application can consume web services that return JSONP object.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**

Following recommendations from @abaghel, I get this error (I suppose I have to create my own HttpMessageConverter):

```
09:54:24,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'jQuery111107193651702763904_1469109722644': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
09:54:24,211 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at [Source: org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream@34dfc6; line: 1, column: 43]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'jQuery111107193651702763904_1469109722644': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
09:54:24,214 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at [Source: org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream@34dfc6; line: 1, column: 43]

09:54:24,216 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:126)

09:54:24,218 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153)

09:54:24,220 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:81)

09:54:24,222 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:454)

09:54:24,223 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:417)

09:54:24,225 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:214)

09:54:24,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at pe.com.equifax.ws.tm.service.impl.MapCityServiceImpl.searchDistricts(MapCityServiceImpl.java:55)

09:54:24,228 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at pe.com.equifax.ws.tm.business.impl.MapCityBusinessImpl.searchDistricts(MapCityBusinessImpl.java:26)

09:54:24,230 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at pe.com.equifax.ws.tm.controller.MapCityController.searchDistricts(MapCityController.java:33)

09:54:24,231 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

09:54:24,233 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

09:54:24,234 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

09:54:24,236 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

09:54:24,237 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)

09:54:24,239 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)

09:54:24,241 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)

09:54:24,242 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)

09:54:24,243 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)

09:54:24,245 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)

09:54:24,246 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)

09:54:24,247 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)

09:54:24,248 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)

09:54:24,249 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)

09:54:24,250 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

09:54:24,251 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

09:54:24,252 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

09:54:24,253 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

09:54:24,254 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

09:54:24,255 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

09:54:24,256 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

09:54:24,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

09:54:24,258 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

09:54:24,259 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

09:54:24,260 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

09:54:24,261 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

09:54:24,262 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

09:54:24,264 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

09:54:24,265 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

09:54:24,266 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'jQuery111107193651702763904_1469109722644': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
09:54:24,267 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at [Source: org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream@34dfc6; line: 1, column: 43]

09:54:24,268 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1576)

09:54:24,269 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533)

09:54:24,270 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3448)

09:54:24,271 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2607)

09:54:24,273 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:841)

09:54:24,274 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:737)

09:54:24,275 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3742)

09:54:24,276 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3687)

09:54:24,277 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2798)

09:54:24,278 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:123)

09:54:24,279 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rest client for JSONP like below.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, params);
System.out.println(result);
```

You should create MediaType like below to avoid error message.

```
MediaType mt = new MediaType("application", "javascript");
```

You can also refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170199/spring-4-mappingjackson2httpmessageconverter-does-not-support-application-javas) post related to application/javascript and jsonp. This post is for Spring 4 but you will get info regarding jsonp and message converters.

Comment: I've followed your advice...but I get a new error. I'm supposing I have to implement my own HttpMessageConverter. Is this correct?

Comment: This should work as you are using String type for response object. Can you check your MessageConverters available for restTemplate using restTemplate.getMessageConverters()? Is webservice returning proper response if you call using Postman?